# Security for AJAX requests from the client side accessing an API

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, security, api

Let's say you want a third party site to copy and paste a snippet of javascript code you provide. This code uses an AJAX request to access a JSON API on your servers. How would you implement security so that, while associating API usage to a website that has signed up and received an API key, you would effectively disallow a site to abuse another site's API key/usage? Is this security not possible from the client side? Must the site access the API from the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can also check HTTP referrer of the request on your server site.
I don't think changing javascript code can fake it.
But it cannot stop someone sending custom package from a custom browser or some http client.

Implementing a server-side solution is possible and not too hard, but it will stop many sites from using your script.
You can let them send the request from their servers
or let them keep the key on their servers, hash the key before sending it to the client (the hashed key changes after a time interval)...

Answer (score -1):

You can just check `window.location`, or some component thereof.

Comment: So you're saying pass the result of `window.location` in the AJAX request to my servers?

Comment: Well, you can't use true AJAX anyway because of cross-domain restrictions.  So typically, sites provide a wrapper API (e.g. https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY), which does JSONP calls.  That script can also look at `window.location` while it's at it.  Then, the issue is if sites try to do the JSONP call directly.

Comment: Yeah, and there's nothing stopping a site from changing the script anyway, or sending false information based on how it sees other sites making the JSONP calls...

Comment: Any ideas on how to restrict sites from making the JSONP call directly?

Comment: @Justin, you can do the `window.location` check in your response to the JSONP call.  E.g., using the Google API example, on every search call, respond with the script `if(isValidDomain()){callback();}`  But that will be a performance hit.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of to enforce such security would be to go by the IP address, but that is risky at best, as there are many reasons why it would be a bad design.

This would be the security on the server-side protecting the javascript file.  You could just have a web service serve up the javascript so it can do the check before ever sending the file to the client.

Comment: What IP address?  You can't hard-code the client IP(s), because neither you nor the third party site know the future users' IPs.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - The fact that you would need to know would be the tough part, and why I think it may not be a perfect solution, but that would probably be the most secure method.  Anything you do in javascript can be hacked.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - part of getting an API key could be to state which IP addresses may be used, so it could be possible to get this information.  This won't stop someone from copying the javascript file in a browser and just putting it on another website.  I think the approach is flawed as javascript is innately not easy to secure.